# AWS MS SQL create table

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, create-table

I have created an AWS MS SQL database following this guide

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.SQLServer.html#CHAP_GettingStarted.Connecting.SQLServer

I can connect to it and use the command

```
Select @@VERSION
```

However, when I try to create a table I get the error

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 CREATE TABLE permission denied in
>   database 'master'.

And the command I tried was

```
CREATE TABLE [RawInput] (
  [DateTime] datetime,
  [Text] text,
  PRIMARY KEY ([DateTime])
);
```

Comment: Switch to **your** database.

Comment: That tutorial is a bit confusing. The query mentioned is related to "exploring your instance". It does not show you how to create a new database in your instance -which you must do before you start creating tables and other database objects **in that newly created database**.  And finally - don't use the text (or any other deprecated) datatype.

Comment: Yeah -- I'm kinda frustrated with this tutorial.  The thing is -- I was even doing "Use [Database]", just not with the same "GO" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed it.

The tutorial I followed did not show all the necessary steps. I have below compiled a list of all the steps I went through:

1) Download and install the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/setup.html#install

2) To login to AWS with Visual Studio, you need to create AWS Credentials 
Go to the AWS console panel and go under Services/IAM/Users - And add new user

3) The newly created credentials are to be provided to Visual Studio.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/credentials.html

4) The database can now be created 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/rds-launch-instance-sql.html

5) The database is now ready and the command can be executed, to create the tables.
Here it is important that you specify the database you would like to write to with the `USE [INSER_NAME_OF_DATABSE]` keyword. Else it will try to write to Master.

Answer (score 3):

**Resolution**:

```
USE [YOUR_DATABASE]
```

**REASON**

**What is `master` database:**

As taken from the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/master-database?view=sql-server-2017

> The master database records all the system-level information for a SQL
>   Server system. This includes instance-wide metadata such as logon
>   accounts, endpoints, linked servers, and system configuration
>   settings. In SQL Server, system objects are no longer stored in the
>   master database; instead, they are stored in the Resource database.
>   Also, master is the database that records the existence of all other
>   databases and the location of those database files and records the
>   initialization information for SQL Server. Therefore, SQL Server
>   cannot start if the master database is unavailable.

Any user level query cannot be run using `master` database because it keeps track of all the other databases

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer, since it says how to fix it, and *why*.

Answer (score 2):

Replace below "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME" with your database name.

```
USE [YOUR_DATABASE_NAME]

CREATE TABLE [RawInput] (
  [DateTime] datetime,
  [Text] text,
  PRIMARY KEY ([DateTime])
);
```